# SQL insert into MS Server DB using Python not working

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert data into a table that has already been created. The code does not throw any error but simply does not writes into the DB.

I think there is problem with the timestamp, may be.

If any of you could please have a look at the code and provide some pointers, that would be great.
TIA!!

Cheers

```
import pyodbc
import datetime
import time

def connect_db():
    db = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                      "Server=xxxxx\SQLEXPRESS;"
                      "Database=test;"
                      "Trusted_Connection=yes;"
                      "uid=xxx;"
                      "password=xyz")
    cursor = db.cursor()



    ts = time.time()
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    sql = "INSERT into dbo.test_tbl VALUES (3,'ITS','Paris', 10, 'Laptop', %)" % (timestamp)
    cursor.execute(sql)
    db.commit()
    cursor.close()
    db.close()
```

Comment: _What_ code?  I don't see any.

Comment: Sorry guys, just added the code. Cheers!

Comment: `ts = time.time(); datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts)` can simplify as `datetime.datetime.now()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 "INSERT into dbo.test_tbl VALUES (3,'ITS','Paris', 10, 'Laptop', %)" % (timestamp)
```

I think you have to add `s` after %

```
"INSERT into dbo.test_tbl VALUES (3,'ITS','Paris', 10, 'Laptop', '%s')" % (timestamp)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Jay. But it's not working. 
Also, the data type in the server is 'datetime'. That should be alright, yeah?

Comment: Try `"INSERT into dbo.test_tbl VALUES (3,'ITS','Paris', 10, 'Laptop', '%s')" % (timestamp)`  @BVenky

Comment: Still not working guys! Although, Intellij IDE is prompting a warning at the table name saying 'no data sources are configured to run this SQL'. Should I configure the DB info in the IDE as well?

Comment: This warning indicates that you have not configured data source in Database Tool Window in Intellij Idea. It doesn't mean that your code is wrong, it just shows that you don't have code completion based on your database schema.

Configuration of datasource in Intellij is described here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/database-tool-window.html

Comment: Yup, I did a google search on that as well. Thanks.

Do you guys think if anything else could be wrong?

Comment: where and how you are calling that function??

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working now. The database schema had to be modified to insert the right data.

Comment: Welcome!! @BVenky